# Change initial range and destination range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie in Excel vba and I'm trying to change a macro from Siddharth Rout (thanks)´.

I need to specify the range to begin in a cell, like B13, and to copy to another worksheet in C14.
How can this be managed?

Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range

'~~> Change Sheet1 to relevant sheet name
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Change Sheet2 to relevant sheet name
        CopyRange.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `CopyRange` is a full row wide you'll need to trim it down before pasting into `Range("B13")`.  As an additional requirement the OP wants to exclude column A from the source range.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim CopyRange As Range

    '~~> Change Sheet1 to relevant sheet name
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Change Sheet2 to relevant sheet name
            Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange, CopyRange).Offset(0, 1).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B13").PasteSpecial xlValues
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.Is gaving error "invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: The `.UsedRange` is supposed to be in the `With Sheets("Sheet1")` block.  Try changing `.UsedRange` to `Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange`.

Comment: Is the one in the post

Comment: OK, that worked after i changed to' Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange, CopyRange).Copy' like you said.

Comment: and to start looking at a cell range, instead of 'A', is the some thing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about using Cells.PasteSpecial? Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 13).PasteSpecial xlValues

Comment: Thanks, but its no that,

Comment: With your your help now is copying to the target that i want. And to define the range to be copied from sheet1, now is A, and to change per exemple to B3?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want to change the data that you are copying? The code copies the entire row.  Do you just want to copy a sub set of the row?  .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 5))

Comment: No. The copy starts from 'With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row'. I want not to start from "A", but from Range B2 to last row.